# How to recover stopped replication on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, replication, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

Several times now my Google Cloud MySQL read replica just stopped replication of the master. Visible symptoms are:

- Replication lags rises
  on the slave.
- The `Relay_Log_Pos` value of `show slave status` is stuck while the `Read_Master_Log_Pos` rises in line with the master.
- On the slave there is an entry for `Reading event from the relay log` that has run very long

So far I had to recreate the read replica to get it working again, but I would like to avoid that.

What can I do to restore proper replication when the slave is stuck like this, without rebuilding the replica?

Comment: Try `STOP SLAVE; START SLAVE;` on the Replica.

Comment: Google Cloud SQL is a managed service. That means only they can run diagnostic commands to debug and fix this issue. Open a support ticket.